# Data mapping XML RPC to JSON

Tags: json, xml, wso2-esb

Is there a way to mapping a XML RPC to Json?

This is the response I get on my endpoint.

https://download.automation.odin.com/pa/6.0/doc/portal/6.0/ba/index.htm?fileName=75131.htm

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodResponse>
<params>
    <param>
        <value>
            <struct>
                <member>
                    <name>Result</name>
                    <value>
                        <array>
                            <data>
                                <value>
                                    <array>
                                        <data>
                                            <!-- OrderID -->
                                            <value>
                                                <i4>16</i4>
                                            </value>
                                            <!-- Order Number -->
                                            <value>
                                                <string>SO000008</string>
                                            </value>
                                            <!-- Vendor Account ID-->
                                            <value>
                                                <i4>1</i4>
                                            </value>
                                            <!-- Customer Account ID-->
                                            <value>
                                                <i4>1000002</i4>
                                            </value>
                                            <!-- Order Status ID-->
                                            <value>
                                                <string>WP</string>
                                            </value>
                                            <!-- Order Type ID-->
                                            <value>
                                                <string>SO</string>
                                            </value>
                                            <!-- Order Creation Time-->
                                            <value>
                                                <i4>1245328433</i4>
                                            </value>
                                            <!-- Order Creation Date-->
                                            <value>
                                                <i4>1245268800</i4>
                                            </value>
                                            <!-- Order Total -->
                                            <value>
                                                <double>85.000000</double>
                                            </value>
                                            <!-- Order Tax Total -->
                                            <value>
                                                <double>0.000000</double>
                                            </value>
                                            <!-- Discount Total -->
                                            <value>
                                                <double>0.000000</double>
                                            </value>
                                            <!-- Order MerchTotal -->
                                            <value>
                                                <double>85.000000</double>
                                            </value>
                                            <!-- Order Description -->
                                            <value>
                                                <string>
                                                    Subscription for Plan 3 (Linux Basic) for 1 Year(s). 
                                                </string>
                                            </value>
                                            <!-- Order Expiration Date-->
                                            <value>
                                                <i4>1245528000</i4>
                                            </value>
                                            <!-- Promo Code-->
                                            <value>
                                                <string/>
                                            </value>
                                            <!-- Sales Branch ID-->
                                            <value>
                                                <string>2</string>
                                            </value>
                                            <!-- Sales Person ID-->
                                            <value>
                                                <string>1</string>
                                            </value>
                                            <!-- CurrencyID-->
                                            <value>
                                                <string>USD</string>
                                            </value>
                                            <!-- CompletedDate-->
                                            <value>
                                                <i4>1453805121</i4>
                                            </value>
                                        </data>
                                    </array>
                                </value>
                            </data>
                        </array>
                    </value>
                </member>
            </struct>
        </value>
    </param>
</params>
```

But in the mapper they group the value as an array

[image: ESB Tooling Data Mapper]

I am new to wso2 esb, and I didn't find any documentation about it.

The XML RPC for this service is purelly array index, e.g.: for get `OrderID` is `['Result'][0][0]` (member, array, array).

So is it possible to use array indexes for bind with json elements??

If with mapper is not possible how can I do it?

== UPDATE ==

The .dmc file

```
var arrayIndex = 0;
map_S_methodResponse_S_root = function(){ 
var outputroot={};
var COMPARE_61_0 = '';
var COMPARE_62_0 = '';
var COMPARE_63_0 = '';
var COMPARE_64_0 = '';
var COMPARE_65_0 = '';
var COMPARE_66_0 = '';
var COMPARE_67_0 = '';
var COMPARE_68_0 = '';
var COMPARE_69_0 = '';
var COMPARE_70_0 = '';
var COMPARE_71_0 = '';
var COMPARE_72_0 = '';
var COMPARE_73_0 = '';
var COMPARE_74_0 = '';
var COMPARE_75_0 = '';
var COMPARE_76_0 = '';
var COMPARE_77_0 = '';
var COMPARE_78_0 = '';
var COMPARE_79_0 = '';
var IF_ELSE_23_0 = '';
var IF_ELSE_25_0 = '';
var IF_ELSE_27_0 = '';
var IF_ELSE_29_0 = '';
var IF_ELSE_31_0 = '';
var IF_ELSE_33_0 = '';
var IF_ELSE_35_0 = '';
var IF_ELSE_37_0 = '';
var IF_ELSE_39_0 = '';
var IF_ELSE_41_0 = '';
var IF_ELSE_43_0 = '';
var IF_ELSE_45_0 = '';
var IF_ELSE_47_0 = '';
var IF_ELSE_49_0 = '';
var IF_ELSE_51_0 = '';
var IF_ELSE_53_0 = '';
var IF_ELSE_55_0 = '';
var IF_ELSE_57_0 = '';
var IF_ELSE_59_0 = '';

var count_i_value = 0;
COMPARE_61_0 = ( arrayIndex === 0 );
COMPARE_62_0 = ( arrayIndex === 1 );
COMPARE_63_0 = ( arrayIndex === 2 );
COMPARE_64_0 = ( arrayIndex === 3 );
COMPARE_65_0 = ( arrayIndex === 4 );
COMPARE_66_0 = ( arrayIndex === 5 );
COMPARE_67_0 = ( arrayIndex === 6 );
COMPARE_68_0 = ( arrayIndex === 7 );
COMPARE_69_0 = ( arrayIndex === 8 );
COMPARE_70_0 = ( arrayIndex === 9 );
COMPARE_71_0 = ( arrayIndex === 10 );
COMPARE_72_0 = ( arrayIndex === 11 );
COMPARE_73_0 = ( arrayIndex === 12 );
COMPARE_74_0 = ( arrayIndex === 13 );
COMPARE_75_0 = ( arrayIndex === 14 );
COMPARE_76_0 = ( arrayIndex === 15 );
COMPARE_77_0 = ( arrayIndex === 16 );
COMPARE_78_0 = ( arrayIndex === 17 );
COMPARE_79_0 = ( arrayIndex === 18 );
outputroot =  {};
outputroot.Result =  {};

for(i_value in inputmethodResponse.params.param.value.struct.member.value.array.data.value.array.data.value){
IF_ELSE_23_0 = (COMPARE_69_0)?(inputmethodResponse.params.param.value.struct.member.value.array.data.value.array.data.value[i_value].double):(IF_ELSE_23_0);
IF_ELSE_25_0 = (COMPARE_70_0)?(inputmethodResponse.params.param.value.struct.member.value.array.data.value.array.data.value[i_value].double):(IF_ELSE_25_0);
IF_ELSE_27_0 = (COMPARE_71_0)?(inputmethodResponse.params.param.value.struct.member.value.array.data.value.array.data.value[i_value].double):(IF_ELSE_27_0);
IF_ELSE_29_0 = (COMPARE_72_0)?(inputmethodResponse.params.param.value.struct.member.value.array.data.value.array.data.value[i_value].double):(IF_ELSE_29_0);
IF_ELSE_31_0 = (COMPARE_62_0)?(inputmethodResponse.params.param.value.struct.member.value.array.data.value.array.data.value[i_value].string):(IF_ELSE_31_0);
IF_ELSE_33_0 = (COMPARE_65_0)?(inputmethodResponse.params.param.value.struct.member.value.array.data.value.array.data.value[i_value].string):(IF_ELSE_33_0);
IF_ELSE_35_0 = (COMPARE_66_0)?(inputmethodResponse.params.param.value.struct.member.value.array.data.value.array.data.value[i_value].string):(IF_ELSE_35_0);
IF_ELSE_37_0 = (COMPARE_73_0)?(inputmethodResponse.params.param.value.struct.member.value.array.data.value.array.data.value[i_value].string):(IF_ELSE_37_0);
IF_ELSE_39_0 = (COMPARE_75_0)?(inputmethodResponse.params.param.value.struct.member.value.array.data.value.array.data.value[i_value].string):(IF_ELSE_39_0);
IF_ELSE_41_0 = (COMPARE_76_0)?(inputmethodResponse.params.param.value.struct.member.value.array.data.value.array.data.value[i_value].string):(IF_ELSE_41_0);
IF_ELSE_43_0 = (COMPARE_77_0)?(inputmethodResponse.params.param.value.struct.member.value.array.data.value.array.data.value[i_value].string):(IF_ELSE_43_0);
IF_ELSE_45_0 = (COMPARE_78_0)?(inputmethodResponse.params.param.value.struct.member.value.array.data.value.array.data.value[i_value].string):(IF_ELSE_45_0);
IF_ELSE_47_0 = (COMPARE_61_0)?(inputmethodResponse.params.param.value.struct.member.value.array.data.value.array.data.value[i_value].i4):(IF_ELSE_47_0);
IF_ELSE_49_0 = (COMPARE_63_0)?(inputmethodResponse.params.param.value.struct.member.value.array.data.value.array.data.value[i_value].i4):(IF_ELSE_49_0);
IF_ELSE_51_0 = (COMPARE_64_0)?(inputmethodResponse.params.param.value.struct.member.value.array.data.value.array.data.value[i_value].i4):(IF_ELSE_51_0);
IF_ELSE_53_0 = (COMPARE_67_0)?(inputmethodResponse.params.param.value.struct.member.value.array.data.value.array.data.value[i_value].i4):(IF_ELSE_53_0);
IF_ELSE_55_0 = (COMPARE_68_0)?(inputmethodResponse.params.param.value.struct.member.value.array.data.value.array.data.value[i_value].i4):(IF_ELSE_55_0);
IF_ELSE_57_0 = (COMPARE_74_0)?(inputmethodResponse.params.param.value.struct.member.value.array.data.value.array.data.value[i_value].i4):(IF_ELSE_57_0);
IF_ELSE_59_0 = (COMPARE_79_0)?(inputmethodResponse.params.param.value.struct.member.value.array.data.value.array.data.value[i_value].i4):(IF_ELSE_59_0);
outputroot.Result.OrderID = IF_ELSE_47_0;
outputroot.Result.OrderNumber = IF_ELSE_31_0;
outputroot.Result.VendorAccountID = IF_ELSE_49_0;
outputroot.Result.AccountID = IF_ELSE_51_0;
outputroot.Result.OrderStatusID = IF_ELSE_33_0;
outputroot.Result.OrderTypeID = IF_ELSE_35_0;
outputroot.Result.CreationTime = IF_ELSE_53_0;
outputroot.Result.CreationDate = IF_ELSE_55_0;
outputroot.Result.CompletedDate = IF_ELSE_59_0;
outputroot.Result.ExpirationDate = IF_ELSE_57_0;
outputroot.Result.CurrencyID = IF_ELSE_45_0;
outputroot.Result.OrderTotal = IF_ELSE_23_0;
outputroot.Result.TaxTotal = IF_ELSE_25_0;
outputroot.Result.DiscountTotal = IF_ELSE_27_0;
outputroot.Result.MerchTotal = IF_ELSE_29_0;
outputroot.Result.Description = IF_ELSE_37_0;
outputroot.Result.PromoCode = IF_ELSE_39_0;
outputroot.Result.SalesBranchID = IF_ELSE_41_0;
outputroot.Result.SalesPersonID = IF_ELSE_43_0;

count_i_value++;
}
return outputroot;
};


arrayIndex = function(val){ arrayIndex++;};
```

It worked after I change, for example, the (COMPARE_61_0)? for (count_i_value == 0)? inside de for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do it. Since in this data mapper version we can not handle objects or arrays in the mapping we have to use a kind of work around for that with the use of custom functions and global variables. But i think it will be in the next release of the data mapper hopefully. For now you can iterate a global variable using a custom function and find the index and assign it to the output element as showed in the attached image.

[image]

Comment: It worked pretty well, but after the first call, it return an empty object.

Comment: Can you share the mapping configuration file (.dmc)